# TextView subclass doesn't wrap words

Tags: android, textview

I'm subclassing TextView in a class named Message and adding instances of this class into a ListView. The problem is that if the text the user sets on the Message class is too wide, the view doesn't wrap words as expected.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things I suspect need to be done:

1. `setSingleLine` to `false` (sounds like you should do it in the constructor of `Message`).
2. Make sure the `layout_height` of the widget you're placing in the `ListView` is `WRAP_CONTENT` (but not the `layout_width`!)

You can also play with `setMinLines` and `setLines` if it better suits your needs.